# Android: Too much allocated memory while using png instead of vector images

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory

I am using 10 png images of size 20-30kb in imageView, but the allocated memory increases from 70mb to 270mb when this activity loads.
So why this too much of memory is allocated to these images.

This is the screenshot of memory allocation

[image]

This is one of my image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

File size doesn't matter. No, matter your image is of 20kb but its resolution is quite big. When image is loaded into memory it takes memory equal to  totalNoOfDotsInImageBitmap * 4bytes
and totalNoOfDotsInImageBitmap = width *height of image.

4 bytes - because of ARBG ( 1 byte per argument) for single dot of bitmap

so reducing width and height of image may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are putting the assets it may be trying to load a file that is too large.

For instance, if you have it on `drawable` or `nodpi-drawable` a device with a low density will try to load a potentially large image.

Also, bear in mind that the actual file size is not that important as it is probably small due to compression, but the image has to be converted to bitmap when it gets drawn, so if the actual size is too much that can also cause an OOM.

If you have access to the original I would recommend using a vector drawable (it's a simple shape so should be ok) and AS will generate the required PNG files for older versions.